# Why is Bilbo's door and Hobbit house so incredibly oversized in Tolkien's own final illustration in The Hobbit?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, j-r-r-tolkien, illustrated-story

Tolkien was a good artist to say the least. He did not have problems with perspective and whatnot in the other illustrations he made for *The Hobbit*, so that can't really be the explanation.

Yet, the final illustration in *The Hobbit*, drawn by Tolkien himself, shows a **GIGANTIC** door which Bilbo could not possibly reach up to the knob to open it, and it looks more like a large hall than a cozy hobbit hole.

I was frankly disappointed and frustrated by this last illustration in the very end of the book. Now I'm going to think of this instead of the far more cozy version which I had imagined in my head, and which is the one part which the movies got right.

I can almost swear that the outside didn't make it look this big, even in Tolkien's own illustrations...

[image]

Comment: Modern human mansions often have huge doors and even double doors. As Bilbo is a very well-to-do Hobbit, it could just be that he has an ostentatious door.

Comment: Don't forget that the door has to accommodate much larger beings that Hobbits. Humans for instance.

Comment: @Paulie_D it doesn't _have_ to, and unless you have evidence I see no reason Bag End should've been built to accommodate larger beings.Bilbo lived at Bag End before even meeting Gandalf for the first time or Dwarves/Men/Elves.

Comment: The size of the door to the left indicates that it is, in fact, a huge door. There is no visible doorknob to indicate the height. The barometre to the left, however, could well be at eye level for a standing hobbit, which means that a typical hobbit would have to reach up a bit to pull the bell string. Overall, these things indicate that the door is about twice hobbit height. Even Gandalf wouldn't have to bend much to enter, and he would be able to stand up comfortly inside, with room even for his tall hat, unless very close to a side wall.

Comment: Perhaps worse than the door is the height of the clock! Mr Bilbo would have to scramble up a stack of chairs just to pull the winding weight!

Comment: I think we have to go for an out-of-universe explanation. 1) Tolkien was more interested in showing hobbits' diminuitive stature more than realistic proportion. 2) Tolkien was an OK artist (certainly better than me) but not a great one. Hence his insistence on having Pauline Baynes illustrate his other works.

Comment: The barometer is well above eye height for Bilbo. A quick measure on my screen has the rug 12 cm wide where Bilbo is, but the perspective lines of the floor take that to 6cm at the door. Bilbo appears 3.5cm high in the foreground, so if he walked to the door he would only appear 1.75cm high. The bottom of the barometer is 1.9cm above the floor and the bell-pull is 2.7cm above the floor. If Bilbo is the average 3.5 feet in actual height then the bell-pull is about 5.5 feet up. However the umbrella stand is about 20" high, which would be about waist height to Bilbo.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen The door knob is directly in the center of the door, as described in the book. As drawn, Bilbo looks too short to reach it (or at least, reach it comfortably).

Comment: @Klaus - The object on the left appears to not be a door but rather a table with a mirror and places to hang hats or cloaks. It seems too tall for Bilbo.

Comment: @FlaStorm32: I miswrote. I meant the *chair* on the left, which is tiny compared to the door.

Comment: "He did not have problems with perspective and whatnot in the other illustrations he made for The Hobbit," well, there's that picture with invisible Bilbo and Smaug where the scale is all off: http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/File:J.R.R._Tolkien_-_Conversation_with_Smaug_(large).jpg

Answer (score 6):

The door does seem rather large here. A few possible explanations:

1. While not necessarily needing to be large enough to accommodate larger beings, it would need to be large enough to accommodate any and all furniture, deliveries, etc., as I presume there is definitely no other opening to get such things in.
2. It was drawn a bit exaggerated to emphasize and symbolize the great wide world/adventure waiting outside.
3. The perspective was difficult to draw correctly on the page dimensions, and the door is intended to appear further away from the viewer (and thus appear smaller) than it actually does.

Comment: This is fairly speculative.  Do you have any evidence that one of these answers is correct?

Comment: Hobbit homes are holes built into hills. And we know he has furniture to accommodate a large group of guests. #2 is definitely speculative. #3 the illustration itself is the evidence.

Answer (score 3):

### Tolkien seems to have not commented on it.

In *J.R.R. Tolkien: Artist and Illustrator*, Wayne Hammond and Christina Scull discuss this drawing, and note the proportion problems, but also note that Tolkien did not ever mention this in his correspondence with his publisher about this illustration.

> *The Hall at Bag-End*, the last illustration in the book, is an intriguing interior. Tolkien enthusiasts have made many deductions about Hobbit culture and crafts from its contents. **Tolkien himself was not happy with it: he confessed to Allen & Unwin that he had misguidedly put a shadow in wash behind the door. which in the line-engraving became all black and obscured a key in the lock. He said nothing to his publisher about the proportions of the door relative to Bilbo, but surely, as drawn the hobbit would have had to stand on a chair to reach the knob.** The drawing has other odd features as well, For example the two framed mirrors on opposite sides of the door, one curved against the wall, the other flat and upright. But these are incidental faults, and they do not detract from the important aspect of the picture: its strong perspective along the lines of the tube-shaped hall to, and through, the open door. It says, on the one hand, that Bilbo is home again, comfortable and (to judge by his paunch) well-fed; but it also says. Look: the door is wide open, and there is the lane beginning just outside, going down The Hill and ‘ever ever on‘ (as Bilbo says in chapter 19), towards the horizon and adventure. Indeed, in less than a year after this drawing was made. Bilbo went once more into the east, in the sequel to *The Hobbit* Tolkien began to write in December 1937: *The Lord of the Rings*.
> <sub>*J.R.R. Tolkien: Artist and Illustrator* - "The Hobbit"</sub>

Nearly two decades later Hammond and Scull again discussed this illustration in their *The Art of the Hobbit* book, but did not have anything further to add about this.

The letter referred to has been partially printed in *The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien*.

> In the 'Hall at Bag-End' I misguidedly put in a wash shadow reaching right up to the side beam. This has of course come out black (with disappearance of the key) though not right up to the beam. But the print is I think as good as the original allows.
> <sub>February 5th 1937 Letter to Allen & Unwin</sub>